# /bin/python3: No module named pip

Tags: centos, package-management, python

I installed `Python 3.4` on `CentOS 7.3`:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install python34.x86_64
```

There was `python 2` installed before under

```
type python
python is hashed (/bin/python)
```

So version 3 is under `python3`:

```
type python3
python3 is hashed (/bin/python3)
```

On Windows, I have version 3.5 and the way I install packages is:

```
python -m pip install <package_name>
```

So I tried the same on CentOS but calling python3 instead of python:

```
python3 -m pip install psycopg2
/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

How do I install or enable pip in Python 3.4 on CentOS so that I can install packages?

Comment: try `yum install python34-pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable epl-repo:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
```

Install `pip`:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install python-pip
pip install -U pip
```

Enable [Software Collections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-python34/):

```
sudo yum install centos-release-scl
sudo yum install scl-utils-build
sudo yum-config-manager --enable rhel-server-rhscl-7-rpms
```

Install the `rh-python34` collection.

```
sudo yum install rh-python34
scl enable rh-python34 bash
```

Install PostgreSQL development header files and libraries:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Install Python development header files and libraries:

```
sudo yum install python-devel
```

Install your package:

```
python3 -m pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: after running the first two commands, i still didn't have yum-config-manager:  `bash: yum-config-manager: command not found`

Comment: run `yum install -y yum-utils`

Comment: i did try `python3 -m pip install psycopg2` but git an error. any chance we can go to chat so i show you the lengthy trace ?

Comment: or i can ask another question

Comment: @amphibient try my edit please

Comment: here is [the new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345814/gcc-error-installing-psycopg2-package-for-python3-on-centos-7-3). thanks in advance.

Comment: i still got the same error, which can be seen in the new question

Comment: this is what fixed it: `sudo yum install postgresql-devel`

Comment: knock-knock:  yet [another related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345837/python-3-under-user-doesnt-see-packages-installed-by-root)

Answer (score 3):

Download this installer script:

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`

Run it as root (or sudo it)

`python3 get-pip.py`

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS 7 you would need to run this:

```
sudo yum install python34-setuptools
sudo easy_install-3.4 pip
```

Edit: You should then be able to install using `pip3 install <package>`

Comment: after installing the setup tools, `bash: easy_install: command not found`

Comment: I'm sorry try this
`sudo easy_install-3.4 pip`