# Python 3 doesn't see packages installed by root under different user

Tags: centos, python, users

I installed `psycopg2` for Python 3 on CentOS 7.3 as root. When I `su` to root

```
> python3 -m  pip show psycopg2
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.6.2
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: http://initd.org/psycopg/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions or ZPL
Location: /opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages
Requires:
```

Note that `pip` installed it in a directory that indicates **root** (`/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages`).

However, when I switch to a different user, python doesn't see this package -- `python3 -m  pip show psycopg2` doesn't return anything. If I try to run a py script that imports it, I get an error. I did confirm that I could go in that directory as a non-root user and read files.

How can I make a python package, that was installed by root, visible to all other users?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, remove `psycopg2` package (`sudo pip uninstall psycopg2`) and then:

1:

Install `python-psycopg2`  package from repositories:

```
$ sudo yum install python-psycopg2
```

**OR**

2:

Change `umask` to `022` and install `psycopg2`

```
$ umask 022
$ sudo pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: I did it but now even root doesn't see it: `python3 -m  pip show psycopg2` returns nothing

Comment: try first option

Comment: that's what i tried

Comment: Did you removed `psycopg2` first?

Comment: Use `pip3` or try `sudo yum install python3-psycopg2`

Comment: yes, i reinstalled everything and am back at where i started

Comment: Search repositories for `psycopg2` package, and install best fit

Answer (score 1):

It was a python pathing issue. I resolved it by introducing a system variable `PYTHONPATH` set to `/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages`:

```
 export PYTHONPATH=/opt/rh/rh-python34/root/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages
```